# Is my TFRecord dataset correctly formatted for a CNN regression model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am very new to machine learning and want to try and use regression predictions with my CNN model. I currently have my image data and labels stored in TFRecords. I see a lot of people using .csv files and pandas when building regression models and I am unsure if my datas current format will work correctly. I load my data from the TFRecords with the code below:

```
def decode_image(image):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE)
    image = tf.reshape(image, [*IMAGE_SIZE, 3])
    return image

def tf_parse(eg):
    example = tf.io.parse_example(
      eg[tf.newaxis], {
          'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
          'num_label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64)
      })
    image =  decode_image(example['image_raw'][0])
    label =   tf.cast(example['num_label'][0], tf.int64)
    return image, label

def load_dataset(filenames, labeled=True):
    ignore_order = tf.data.Options()
    ignore_order.experimental_deterministic = False  # disable order, increase speed
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
        filenames
    )  # automatically interleaves reads from multiple files
    dataset = dataset.with_options(
        ignore_order
    )  # uses data as soon as it streams in, rather than in its original order
    dataset = dataset.map(
        partial(tf_parse), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE
    )
    # returns a dataset of (image, label) pairs if labeled=True or just images if labeled=False
    return dataset

def get_dataset(filenames, labeled=True):
    dataset = load_dataset(filenames, labeled=labeled)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    return dataset

train_dataset = get_dataset(train_filenames)
valid_dataset = get_dataset(valid_filenames)
test_dataset = get_dataset(test_filenames)
```

Below is very basic model architecture that I have made

```
def make_model(fine_tune =0):
    
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.Xception(include_top = False, weights='imagenet', input_shape= (*IMAGE_SIZE,3))
    
    if fine_tune > 0:
        for layer in base_model.layers[:-fine_tune]:
            layer.trainable = False
    else:
        for layer in base_model.layers:
            layer.trainable = False
            
    top_model = base_model.output
    top_model = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(top_model)
    top_model = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(top_model)
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(top_model)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs=output_layer)
    
    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=initial_learning_rate),
        loss = 'mse',
    )
    return model


model = make_model()
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
    validation_data=valid_dataset
)
```

Comment: "The tf.data API enables you to build complex input pipelines from simple, reusable pieces." from this [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data). You can as well use Pandas if your problem statement is simpler. For the sake of the code reference, you can check the example as given [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/data.ipynb) which should work. Thank you.